# svn accept certificate permanently for all users

Tags: linux, svn, centos, ssl-certificate

So I have a certificate issue with a third party svn server and fixing it right now is not an option for me. When I ssh into my server I can trust the certificate but it only applies for the user I'm logged in as. Right now to accept the certificate permenantly I just do:

```
svn info "https://www.example.com/repo"
```

and I get the following message

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://www.example.com:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: www.example.com
 - Valid: from Mon, 21 Jan 2013 00:49:57 GMT until Thu, 24 Mar 2016 12:18:43 GMT
 - Issuer: GeoTrust, Inc., US
 - Fingerprint: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

and then I hit `p` to accept it permanently. The problem is when I log in as a different user I get the same certificate warning. Is there any way to accept the certificate permanently for my account and all existing accounts at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

As per [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.ssl.client), when you hit 'p',

> Subversion will cache the server certificate in your private runtime
>   auth/ area, just as your username and password are cached.

On unix/linux, this caching happens under each user's home directory. ( See [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache) for more information)

So you need to understand the caching and then put the certificate at appropriate place.

HTH